# MAPISendMail Outlookで送信すると送信されない

Tags: c++

Outlookを起動していない状況でMAPISendMailで送信画面を出して送信しても直ぐに送信されません。この操作の後にOutlookを起動すると送信されます。
Outlookを起動している状況ではMAPISendMailで送信画面を出して送信して直ぐに送信されます。

Outlookを起動していなくても、直ぐに送信されるようにしたいです。
MAPISendMailの引数などで状況が変わるように成るのでしょうか？
あるいは、Outlookの設定でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

SMTP の送信プロトコルには パスワード認証が必要ありませんが、
プロバイダ（メールサーバー）によっては、事前にユーザ名パスワードを必要とする 「受信」
の後でのみ送信可能としている設定の物があります。

Outlook で 「受信」で認証された アカウントなので MAPISendMail で「送信」
できるようになったのかもしれません。

Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4865

等で、ネットワークパケットをキャプチャして、サーバーの応答を確認すると、何かヒントがつかめるかもしれません。